# News articles database - should I use index on date_publish field for faster SELECTS

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Need some advice on how to optimize my articles table for read operations. I have articles table where I store articles editors write. There is requirement that editors can enter an article with a date_publish set in future. These articles can not be displayed in cover page at any time until the publish_date has actually come.

So my question here is should I have an index on date_publish field for better performance? I am using `MySQL database`, with `InnoDB` engine. I store dates as `unixtimestamps` in `unsigned INT(11)` field.

I when I make a read for list articles for cover page I do something like this:

```
SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE date_publish < $time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an index on the column `date_publish` would optimize the following simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE date_publish < $time
```

However, if you change the query, such as add an `ORDER` clause to order by a column other than `date_publish`, you may need a compound (multi-column) index to optimize the query.

**EDIT**

To be able to fully utilize an index, a "covering" index must include all columns in the `WHERE`, `JOIN` and `ORDER` clauses, usually in that order. So, if you have a range in your `WHERE` clause on date_publish, and `ORDER BY` article_name, then you may wish to index on both columns (date_publish, article_name). That way MySQL can use the index for both selection and sorting.

Comment: I am actually having reads with `ORDER` clause, so I am curious what did you mean by "multi-column" index for optimization?

Comment: I'm updating my answer to explain further.